# HTTP interceptor doesn't work when on npm

Tags: angular, npm

I'm building a front-end local storage database to simplify front-end development. I've created an HTTP interceptor that works fine when used from scratch in an app. To implement it, I just add the following to my app.module.ts:

```
providers: [    {      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,      useClass: PulsarDBInterceptor,      multi: true    }  ]
```

Afterward, I tried exporting this interceptor as an npm package by publishing it as a library on npmjs.com. I've imported the new package into my project; it appears in my dependencies and in my node_modules, but it no longer works.

In fact, when an HTTP request is sent, the interceptor does its job and captures it. It saves the data to local storage but doesn't send the data back. So, when I use a GET method, I receive an empty observable. I've added some logs, and I can see that the interceptor receives and reads the data correctly. However, the data seems to get lost during the transfer.

You can find my npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pulsar-db?activeTab=code). I'm using Angular 15 for the library and for the test project.

- I try adding some logs
- I try to import the library from my local disk instead of npm
- I try to recompile the library.

There is the code of the interceptor

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PulsarDBInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {
        console.log('------------------------------')
        console.log("Vous utilisez pulsar-db. Attention, ce n'est pas fait pour un environnement de production.");
        console.log("------------------------------");
    }

    private getTableInfo(url: string) {
        const segments = url.split('/');
        let lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

        const isANumber = !isNaN(Number(lastSegment));

        if (isANumber) {
            return {tableName: segments[segments.length - 2], isNumber: Number(lastSegment)};
        }

        return {tableName: lastSegment, isNumber: isANumber};
    }

    intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
        console.log("Interception en cours...");

        const {tableName, isNumber} = this.getTableInfo(req.url);

        if (req.url.includes('/api/')) {
            console.log(`Intercepté une requête vers ${req.url} avec la méthode ${req.method}`);
            switch (req.method) {
                case 'GET':
                    console.log(`GET sur la table ${tableName} avec isNumber=${isNumber}`);
                    return isNumber ? this.getItemFromTable(tableName, Number(isNumber)) : this.getAllItemFromTable(tableName);
                case 'DELETE':
                    console.log(`DELETE sur la table ${tableName} avec isNumber=${isNumber}`);
                    return isNumber ? this.deleteItemFromTable(tableName, Number(isNumber)) : this.deleteAllItemFromTable(tableName);
                case 'POST':
                    console.log(`POST sur la table ${tableName}`);
                    return this.saveItemInTable(tableName, req);
                default:
                    console.log("Méthode HTTP non gérée");
                    return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 200}));
            }
        }

        return of(new HttpResponse<T>({status: 200}));
    }

    deleteAllItemFromTable(tableName: string) {
        this.removeFromLocalStorage(tableName);
        return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 200}));
    }

    getAllItemFromTable(tableName: string) {
        const tests = this.parseLocalStorage(tableName);
        return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 201, body: tests}));
    }

    getItemFromTable(tableName: string, id: number) {
        const tests = this.parseLocalStorage(tableName);
        return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 201, body: tests.find(t => t.id === id)}));
    }

    saveItemInTable(tableName: string, request: HttpRequest<any>) {
        const table = this.parseLocalStorage(tableName) as any;

        table.push(request.body);
        this.addToLocalStorage(tableName, JSON.stringify(table));

        return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 201, body: request.body}));
    }

    deleteItemFromTable(tableName: string, id: number) {
        const items = this.parseLocalStorage(tableName);
        let idx = items.findIndex(t => t.id === id);

        if (idx !== -1) {
            this.deleteAllItemFromTable(tableName);
            items.splice(idx, 1);
            this.addToLocalStorage(tableName, JSON.stringify(items));
        }

        return of(new HttpResponse<any>({status: 200}));
    }

    private parseLocalStorage(tableName: string): any[] {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(tableName) || '[]');
    }

    private removeFromLocalStorage(tableName: string): void {
        return localStorage.removeItem(tableName);
    }

    private addToLocalStorage(tableName: string, object: string) {
        return localStorage.setItem(tableName, object);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api

Comment: Please provide more detail and add  `PulsarDBInterceptor` to the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the information i will take a look at your suggestion.

You can find the code in the code section of the lib but i will edit my question to add the code to it

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i take a look at angular-in-memory-web-api, that's a great project but not exactly what i want to do. 
I'm still trying to make that lib work.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was with my publish process. By navigating to my code directory, executing `ng build`, and then moving to the `dist/` directory to run `npm publish`, everything now works fine.